# Broadlink BCM4313 Driver problem

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom

My Ubuntu version is 13.10

I have issues with my Wi-Fi. When I boot up my OS, the signal of my WiFi show very less or no strength. I have to disable (Software Updater>Additional Drivers>Do not use this device and Apply) and then enable it. Then only it shows full strength. Have to repeat it every time I boot up.

PS: Moreover why does ifconfig command shows my WiFi as eth1 and not wlan0 after doing above steps?

Please help. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe -rv wl
sudo modprobe -v brcmsmac
```

if there are any errors please continue with the commands then reboot. your wireless should be working now.

eth1 is showing because you are using the wl driver which is no longer the best driver for your device since 13.04 came out.